# Where can I check Consecutive Days in mobile view?

Tags: support, feature-request, profile-page, mobile-web

Say I'm trying to finish a badge for consecutive days, and I want to verify that I've contributed today. Where can I see that information in the mobile site?

This image shows my profile as seen with a desktop user agent:

[image]

In mobile browsers, with a mobile user agent, the last four items are not present. If I switch the user agent to Desktop, I'm able to see them.

Are they available in mobile view?

Answer (score 25):

No they are not available, neither in SE app. Just checked them both. This is quite interesting and IMHO should be available on both platforms.